# Average of two consecutive elements in the list in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of even number of float numbers:

> [2.34, 3.45, 4.56, 1.23, 2.34, 7.89, ...].

My task is to calculate average of 1 and 2 elements, 3 and 4, 5 and 6, etc. What is the short way to do this in Python?

Comment: How would a good extension look for aggregating each time n>=2 instead of strictly 2 values?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
data = [2.34, 3.45, 4.56, 1.23, 2.34, 7.89]
print [(a + b) / 2 for a, b in zip(data[::2], data[1::2])]
```

Explanation:

`data[::2]` is the elements `2.34, 4.56, 2.34`

`data[1::2]` is the elements `3.45, 1.23, 7.89`

`zip` combines them into 2-tuples: `(2.34, 3.45), (4.56, 1.23), (2.34, 7.89)`

Comment: Nice usage of `zip` and list comprehension! Makes the computation lean and efficient.

Comment: Great, i would have used `range`, a for loop, etc. ...

Comment: What if the desired end result is the average of [0, 1], [1, 2], [2,3]...,[n-1, n] for a data sent of length n? In this case, the list is only advancing one element rather than skipping one, but I am having trouble with the indexing in this response (as elegant as it is).

Comment: I figured it out. `[(a + b) / 2 for a, b in zip(data[:-1], data[1::])]` What threw me off was the need for 3 addresses in one and 2 in the other. The first of the tuples is saying all of the list except for the last element, and the second tuple is asking for every member of the list starting at 1 (the second element).

Answer (score 13):

If the list is not too long, Paul Draper's answer is easy. If it *is* really long, you probably want to consider one of two other options.

---

First, using iterators, you can avoid copying around giant temporary lists:

```
avgs = [(a + b) / 2 for a, b in zip(*[iter(data)]*2)]
```

This does effectively the same thing, but *lazily*, meaning it only has to store one value at a time in memory (well, three values—a, b, and the average) instead of all of them.

- `iter(data)` creates a lazy iterator over the data.
- `[iter(data)]*2` creates a list with two references to the same iterator, so when one advances, the other does as well.
- Then we're using the same `zip` and list comprehension that Paul already explained so well. (In Python 2.x, as opposed to 3.x, `zip` is not lazy, so you're want to use `itertools.izip` rather than `zip`.)

If you don't actually need the result list, but just something you can iterate over, change the outer square brackets to parentheses and it becomes a generator expression, meaning it gives you an iterator instead of a list, and you're not storing anything at all.

Notice that the [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) docs have a recipe for a `grouper` that does the tricky bit (and you can also find it in the third-party module [`more-itertools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/more-itertools)), so you can just write `grouper(data, 2)` instead of `zip(*[iter(data)]*2)`, which is certainly more readable if you're doing it frequently. If you want more explanation, see [How grouper works](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-grouper-works.html).

---

Alternatively, you could use [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org) arrays instead of lists:

```
data_array = np.array(data)
```

And then you can just do this:

```
avg_array = (data_array[::2] + data_array[1::2]) / 2
```

That's not only simpler (no need for explicit loops), it's also about 10x faster, and takes about 1/4th the memory.

---

If you want to generalize this to arbitrary-length groups…

For the iterator solution, it's trivial:

```
[sum(group) / size for group in zip(*[iter(data)]*size)]
```

For the NumPy solution, it's a bit trickier. You have to dynamically create something to iterator over `data[::size]`, `data[1::size]`, …, `data[size-1::size]`, like this:

```
sum(data[x::size] for x in range(size)) / size
```

There are other ways to do this in NumPy, but as long as `size` isn't too big, this will be fine—and it has the advantage that the exact same trick will work for Paul Draper's solution:

```
[sum(group) / size for group in zip(*(data[x::size] for x in range(size)))]
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to make it generic by taking out the unpacking and make it so that the only variable is the group size: `avgs = [sum(vals, 0.0) / size for vals in zip(*[iter(data)]*size)]` or similar

Comment: @JonClements: I linked to "How grouper works" which should explain how to do the hard part of that, but yeah, it might be worth explaining the easy part (using `sum` instead of `+`) as well… except that I think your comment already says all that's needed.

Comment: @JonClements: On second thought, I think it _was_ worth explaining, to show how the "simple" solution is actually harder to expand to arbitrary/dynamic sizes than the two "hard" solutions. So, thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: @abarnet and the "there are other ways to do this in NumPy" would be something like: `np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).reshape(3, 2).mean(axis=1)` ?

Comment: @JonClements: Yeah, but to generalize that as-is, you have to compute the shape as `(len(data)//size, size)`, which is starting to get ugly, so at that point I think it's time to start factoring parts of this into a function.

Comment: @JonClements: There wasn't a missing `)`. The `/ size` is outside the `sum`. So I rolled back your change. (You can test it by just pasting the line into your interpreter.)

Comment: @abarnet How strange. I thought it odd you'd let something like that slip, and kept looking at it, and thought - okay, better correct that one. Then looking at it this morning - there is indeed absolutely nothing wrong. Good intent didn't quite overcome tired eyes it would appear. My apologies.

Answer (score 5):

```
s= [2.34, 3.45, 4.56, 1.23, 2.34, 7.89, ...]

res= [(s[i]+s[i+1])/2 for i in range(0, len(s)-1, 2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using NumPy to find the mean/average of consecutive two values this is more efficient in terms of Time and Space Complexity:

```
data=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
k=2 #In your case
data1=np.mean(data.reshape(-1, k), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use index for the task.

For simple example,

```
avg = []
list1 = [2.34, 3.45, 4.56, 1.23, 2.34, 7.89]

for i in range(len(list1)):
    if(i+1 < len(list1):
        avg.append( (list1[i] + list1[i+1]) / 2.0 )

avg2 = []
avg2 = [j for j in avg[::2]]
```

avg2 is what you want. This maybe easy to understand..

Comment: Please, avoid using indexes to access data in sequences, and take care not to use `list` as variable name: `for elem_odd, elem_even in zip( data[::2], data[1::2]): print (elem_odd + elem_even)/2.0,` is much leaner.

Comment: @Joël: Depends what you mean by "leaner". His version's total storage cost is 3 floats; your is 3 lists and 2*N floats. If N is 6, who cares. But if N is 1000000, that's not exactly an improvement.

Comment: @abarnert I mean straightforward, but you're right, this may be an improvement if performance is needed, as you store only one list. But in my algorithm, if I'm not wrong, `elem_odd` and `elem_even` are stored only once, even if I create three list (as Paul Draper's answer). Nota: `zip` is lazy in Python3, thus this would create only two lists.

Comment: @Joël: I know `zip` is lazy in Python 3, but your code is clearly Python 2, since it uses `print` as a statement. Meanwhile, you're right that you don't create 2*N new floats, but you do still create 3*N list slots (in CPython terms, only 2 extra `PyFloatObject`s, but 3*N extra pointers). Anyway, you can get around that by using `itertools.islice` instead of list slicing, but I think at that point you're better of just grouping by iterator in the first place (as in my answer).