# Get average between consecutive pairs of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Say I have a numpy array like this

`[1,2,3,4,5]`

I want to generate an array that is the equal to the average of consecutive elements

`[1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5]`

Is there any efficient way to do this outside of just iterating through?

I'm not really sure what to do because reshaping doesn't really work and I'm trying to get a smaller array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Average of two consecutive elements in the list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527563/average-of-two-consecutive-elements-in-the-list-in-python)

Comment: @MetinUsta That's asking about every pair of elements without overlapping, which is different. And it's not about NumPy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.convolve`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) to implement two-element averaging as the [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) of the input vector with the vector `[0.5, 0.5]`:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> np.convolve(a, [0.5, 0.5], "valid")
array([1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5])
```

`np.convolve` is a highly optimized routine, and will delegate to different implementations depending on what it estimates will be fastest for the given inputs. For small vectors like `[0.5, 0.5]` it will likely just compute the result directly (`0.5*a[n] + 0.5*[n+1]` for each element), but for large inputs it can leverage [FFT-based convolution algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Fast_convolution_algorithms) to compute the result with significantly fewer operations than the direct method.

Comment: How does convolve compare in efficiency versus the answers `0.5*(x[1:] + x[:-1])`

Comment: @redrobinyum Your best bet is to profile it on your system and find out. It's highly dependent on what libraries / instruction sets your numpy installation uses in the background. On my system, using `x=np.arange(1_000_000)`, I get `2.1 ms ± 132 µs` for `%timeit np.convolve(x, [0.5, 0.5], "valid")` and `2.37 ms ± 111 µs` for `%timeit 0.5*(x[1:] + x[:-1])`

Comment: @redrobinyum Also, do make sure that you profile using arrays of roughly the same size as your actual use case. This is always a good practice, since fixed vs asymptotic costs can have different significance at different input scales, but is also particularly important when using `np.convolve`, since it may choose different convolution implementations depending on the input size. See my edit.